# Using CSV file on MySQL Workbench without insert/create a table

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, mysql-workbench

I have a csv file which consists of list of my customer contacted me. I would like to read the csv file using MySQL Workbench and get the full details about my contacted customer.

There are only one SCHEMA in MySQL database. I can' create a new one. I dont have use rights to create one.

I have used "Create Temporary Table" option but I am getting error "Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user '*****'@'%' to database 'test'"

Please help me to read the csv file.

Comment: Can someone help me read csv in MySQL Workbench without using INSERT query. Because, I dont have rights to insert datas into my database. I just want to read the csv file and get output based on the csv on mysql

Comment: MySQL Workbench is not a general CSV import tool. If you import CSV data it will alway be inserted into a table. That being said, there might be a way: open any connection and run a simple select query on any table you have (maybe one which returns an empty result set). Then use the CSV import tool (see button on the toolbar) to import the CSV which should then appear in the result set table. Now you can look at the data, but don't commit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could import it into MS Access / LibreOffice Base / OpenOffice and work on your file with that. 
It will give you all the SQL functionalities you're looking for, and will not ask you for rights, since you will be creating a file on your own with one of these softwares, and not interact with an existing base.

It will only require you to specify what type data is in each row, so the datatable can be created.

It will be like Excel/Calc but with SQL functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I do know Access, but my client want to work on these two platform only. they dont want to change the input and output. 
Is there any way to read csv file on MySQL without insert into SQL database

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. It looked like you just wanted to easily go through a file, but now it looks like the client has to import it into the DB. So, no, there is no way to read it without importing it. You can read the CSV in Excel/Calc but you won't be able to easily use the worksheet. The best option to just read the file is Access/Base, or create a Table in MySQL.